# how I can create a specific phone id a trigger for sending sms?

Tags: vonage

I  want to create an Autoresponder, I want to send SMS just if I
get a phone calls to a specific number. 
for example, if my phone ID is 1111 I want that just if someone calls to 1111
he will get SMS

I tried to create a condition for my phone ID but with no success.
this is my code before the condition.

```
package getstarted;

import com.nexmo.client.NexmoClient;
import com.nexmo.client.auth.AuthMethod;
import com.nexmo.client.auth.TokenAuthMethod;
import com.nexmo.client.sms.SmsSubmissionResult;
import com.nexmo.client.sms.messages.TextMessage;

 public class SendSMS {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    AuthMethod auth = new TokenAuthMethod("zzzzz","yyyyy");
    NexmoClient client = new NexmoClient(auth);

    TextMessage message = new TextMessage("5555", "9723455555", "Hello from Nexmo!");
    SmsSubmissionResult[] responses = client.getSmsClient().submitMessage(message);
    for (SmsSubmissionResult response : responses) {
        System.out.println(response);
    }
}
```

}

```
// We're creating a Java Application:
  apply plugin: 'application'
  apply plugin: 'java'

// Download dependencies from Maven Central:
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

// Install the Nexmo Client library:
dependencies {
compile 'com.nexmo:client:2.0.1'
```

}

```
 // We'll create this class to contain our code:
mainClassName = "getstarted.SendSMS"
```

Answer (score 0):

When you receive a call to a Nexmo number, a webhook is sent to the `answer_url` that you configure for that number. You can write some code there to respond to the incoming calls as you wish. In this case you might want to collect the incoming phone number and send an SMS to it. You could also answer and give an automated spoken message letting the user know they'll receive an SMS.

Hope that gives you an idea of the overall workflow - good luck with your project :)